# 'invalid arguments' error message when loading array of Files

Tags: javascript

Let's have the following page:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>

<div><input type="file" id="file0" onchange="readFile(event)" /></div>
<div><input type="file" id="file1" onchange="readFile(event)" /></div>
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendFile()" />

<script>

var glob = new Array();

function readFile(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    glob.push(input.files[0]);
    console.log(glob);
}

function sendFile() {
    var i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < glob.length ; i++) {
        console.log(glob[i].name);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var arr = reader.result;
            var uint8View = new Uint8Array(arr);      
            console.log(uint8View);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(glob[i]);
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm loading 2 files from my computer and click on "send". But I'm receiviving error message on console in FF: `TypeError: invalid arguments`. Different error message in IE: `Typed array constructor argument is invalid`. Seems to me that problem is with `Uint8Array()` but what's wrong? If I send a single file it is okay.

Comment: What is `arr`?  What does it actually contain?  I presume its a string.

Comment: @Amy: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result). For a successful call to `readAsArrayBuffer`, it's an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh!  that's part of JS!  I was under the impression it was some custom class.  nevermind then

Comment: `reader` no longer refers to the reader as of when `onload` fires, because you've updated the variable with a new value. So you're accessing `result` on the **last** `FileReader`, which probably isn't complete yet. This is the classic closure-in-loops problem.  You could just use `this` instead of `reader` in the callback, or use the various solutions in the linked question's answers.

Comment: @Amy: Well, not JavaScript, but the File API which is implemented in modern browsers, yes. :-) (`ArrayBuffer` is built into JavaScript, though, if that's what you meant.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I was struggling with this for hours..... it is working with `this`... thanks :D